# Unable to Use the OpenGL Core Profile and Create and OpenGL 4.x Context

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-4

I am trying to develop simple OpenGL applications using the programmable pipeline, specifically using OpenGL 4.2+, but my programs seem to be stuck using OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL 1.30.

The output from `glxinfo |grep "OpenGL"` on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine is as follows:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I've created a simple program which I believe should initialise an OpenGL 4.2 context:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Test");
    glutInitContextVersion (4, 2);
    glutInitContextProfile (GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    if(glewInit() == GLEW_OK)
    {
        cout << "GLEW initialization successful! " << endl;
        cout << "Using GLEW version " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << 
endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW  ...exiting." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
    cout << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << endl;
}
```

However, when I run this program the following output is printed to the console, showing the the OpenGL version used is 3.0 and the GLSL version used is 1.3.

```
GLEW initialization successful! 
Using GLEW version 2.0.0
3.0 Mesa 18.0.5    # OpenGL version
1.30               # GLSL Version
```

I am compiling and running my program as follows:

```
g++ OpenGLTest.cpp -o OpenGLTest -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lGLEW
./OpenGLTest
```

What I am doing wrong or what else could I try to fix this?

Comment: Try adding `glewExperimental = true;` infront of `glewInit()`, furthermore, I wouldnt mix glew and glut for context creation.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you have to set profile flag and version **before** creating context - or, in that case, window.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann GLEW never creates contexts.

Comment: @keltar moving the two glutInitContext lines above the glutCreateWindow call solved it for me! Thank you so much. Please add your solution as an answer so that I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glutInitContextVersion` and such sets parameters to be used for next context creation; all contexts that are already created will not be affected. That is true for many libraries, not just freeglut (e.g. SDL behaves the same way). As far as I can tell there is no dedicated function to create contexts in GLUT - context is created as part of window creation, so you need to set your parameters before calling `glutCreateWindow`.